# How can i make a two toned hr tag?

Tags: html, linear-gradients, css

I am making a divider line that runs across the bottom of my header. It needs to be two pixels tall and two-toned. The top pixel needs to be grey horizontally all the way across, the bottom needs to be white. I am tempted to just put two one pixel divs with 100% width on top of each other, but am hoping that someone knows of a better way to do this with css and maybe with an hr tag?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid the `<hr />` tag because it's really inconsistent in different browsers. And honestly I haven't seen it being used for a while.

What you can do is to place a 100% wide `<p>` and give it a top and a bottom color - http://jsfiddle.net/zSXya/

```
p.separator {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: I agree with Zoltan.  If you need something custom as opposed to generic, just recreate the effect with a `p` or `div`.  maybe 90% wide. EDIT: also, you might need `line-height:0px;` to adjust for browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach would be to use a 1-by-2 pixel image as the background to a div that will stretch horizontally across the page:

```
.myCustomHRule
{
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(path/to/my/image.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: this could be really useful for adding shadows and other effects too.. will save this snippet

Answer (score 1):

typically it's just the top and bottom border attributes.  You can change them and then set the style to solid:

http://jsbin.com/ixuyoz/

```
  hr{
    border-top-color: red;
    border-bottom-color: lime;
    border-style: solid;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use border-bottom of your header and border-top of your first TR?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the HR, you can set it's background to be an image.

```
hr
{
height:2px;
background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
}

<hr />
```

Comment: no-repeat?  Personally I think CSS only would be far superior to loading a whole image, but even if you use an image, use a 1px x 2px image and **repeat** it.  Otherwise you're really creating too much overhead for such a small effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Zoltan with this being the best way to do it. I also haven seen an HR tag in a long time. easier done this was and will have a more consistent look across browsers

```
p.separator {
height: 0;
width: 100%;
border: 0;
border-top: 1px solid red;
border-bottom: 1px solid green;
```

}